# How to send binary data via JQuery Ajax PUT method

Tags: jquery, ajax, upload, binaryfiles, put

I am new to JQuery and
I want to use JQuery Ajax to upload some files to server, Only in PUT method. 
when I send some binary file(such as gif or jpeg) to my server, upload succeed, but the content of binary data was changed(it's always bigger than original file size). 
I try to change the content-type or the type of file result, but still not work.
Anyone knows how to fix this?

PS: I cannot encode the binary file's content into other form, because I cannot touch the code of server.

```
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onloadend = (function(Thefile) {

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        processData:false,
        //contentType:"application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8",
        data: file.result,
        type: 'PUT',
        success : function(){console.log("OK!");},
        error : function(){console.log("Not OK!");}
    }); 
})(file);

reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
```

Comment: I've encountered a similar issue. My first guess is that this has to do with the way the `ajax` function processes data before sending the request.

Comment: Regardless of the jQuery AJAX machinery, notice you should assign a function to reader.onloadend - not invoke that function yourself!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most (all?) browsers will automatically convert string datatypes to UTF-8 when sending them via an `XMLHttpRequest`. When you read the file as a binary string, you're given exactly that: a JavaScript string object where each character is a value between 0 and 255.

To force the AJAX request to send binary encoded data, the data parameter must be an `ArrayBuffer`, `File`, or `Blob` object.

If you need access to the contents of the file before sending, you can convert the binary string to an `ArrayBuffer` with the following code:

```
var arrBuff = new ArrayBuffer(file.result.length);
var writer = new Uint8Array(arrBuff);
for (var i = 0, len = file.result.length; i < len; i++) {
    writer[i] = file.result.charCodeAt(i);
}
```

And you'd pass the `arrBuff` instance to the AJAX function. Otherwise, you should be able to pass the `File` object itself into the AJAX function without all of your `FileReader` code.